# Is it possible to have a DataColumn with a space in the name and how can I do it?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a DataTable that I am creating and binding to a GridView. Currently the headers do not have any spaces and it makes it hard to read. I want to space them out but I'm having a minor issue.

What I am trying to accomplish :

```
Dim dc As Data.DataColumn
dc = New Data.DataColumn("Updated Date", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
dt.Columns.Add(dc)
```

What I currently have :

```
Dim dc As Data.DataColumn
dc = New Data.DataColumn("UpdatedDate", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
dt.Columns.Add(dc)
```

I know that I can set the HeaderText in the columns declaration like below, but I won't know how any columns I am going to have. And would rather the columns be generated automatically.

```
<Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UpdatedDate" HeaderText="Updated Date" />
</Columns>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe names should not contain spaces, unless you want to create yourself bigger problems later. You can generate the column titles automatically by writing a line of code that inserts a space every time there is a capital letter in the name.

Comment: I feel like an idiot. I was able to just put a space in the name and it worked

Answer (score 2):

You might not want to use the constructor, and instantiate a column. This way you can set a property like below:

```
Dim col As New GridViewColumn()
col.DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding("UpdatedDate")
col.Header = "Updated Date"
dt.Columns.Add(col)
```

Hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: That looks interesting. I'd use that but this project is on 2.0 and after looking at MSDN it looks like that is 3.0 and up.